# where is gradle properties file located in gradle project?

Tags: grails, gradle, ggts

Where does the `gradle.properties` file located in Grails/Gradle project?
I tried but not able to find it. 
I have build the Gradle project using command line.
and what is the major purpose of that file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 possible location for `gradle.properties` file:

1. project build dir
2. gradle user home

Note, `gradle.properties` file is not necessary located within your projects files. If it's absent, look for it in your gradle user home directory (as in users guide said: it's defined by the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` environment variable, which if not set defaults to `USER_HOME/.gradle`).

It's used to configure Java process, used to build your project.

You can read more about it in the [Gradle official user guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties)