# The option setting 'android.keepTimestampsInApk=true' is experimental and unsupported

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

How do I get rid of this warning in Android Studio Gradle project:

```
The option setting 'android.keepTimestampsInApk=true' is experimental and unsupported.
```

String 'keepTimestampsInApk' is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Did U checked in gradle.properties ??

Comment: it's there indeed! thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [SkorpEN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1331578/skorpen) said in the comments, `android.keepTimestampsInApk` can be found in the file `gradle.properties`.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444581/where-is-gradle-properties-file-located-in-gradle-project) by [Stanislav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4053652/stanislav), there are two possible locations for the `gradle.properties` file:

1. project build dir
2. gradle user home (defined by the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` environment variable, which if not set defaults to `USER_HOME/.gradle`)